# How to change the Browser Object Model version Window object "DispHTMLWindow2" to "Window" in Javascript for IE5 Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, dom-events, javascript-objects

Here, am checking the browser BOM object windows version in IE5 browser. It isshowing `[object DispHTMLWindow2]` and condition true object create regarding with the version. I need the object to change in "Window" how to change the BOM version in Javascript.

Note : I am not able to change the browser version IE5.

Error : This client Javascript is lower version. We tried communication with the PHP server but it is not supporting the version of Javascript, but if I run the application in higher version like Edge and IE11 its working fine and the BOM object is Window, that's why I'm trying to change the BOM version value.

```
function HPF_Click() {
    var currentLocation = document.getElementById("ddlurl").value;
    var objectType = document.getElementById("ddlobject").value;
    var activexModes = ["Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]; // For ActiveX
    var logUrl = currentLocation;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        for (var i = 0; i < activexModes.length; i++) {
            try {
                Ajax = new ActiveXObject(activexModes[i]);
                if (Ajax)
                    break;
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }  
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        Ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }   

    if (Ajax && currentLocation) {
        postData = "messagedata";
        Ajax.open('POST', logUrl, true);
        Ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        
        Ajax.send(postData);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking. *Where* are you seeing "[object DispHTMLWindow2]"? Where do you want "Window" instead? (Side note: That code needs `var Ajax` to [avoid creating a global variable](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).)

Comment: Are you testing with the IE 5 browser or the IE 5 document mode? It is a too old browser and out of support scope of Microsoft. I suggest you should at least move to the IE 11 browser where your code can work without any issue. Let us know if I am misunderstanding something. Please also inform on which line you are having an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. our application run in IE5 compatibility mode alone. we are start to upgrade our application to Edge.